# install error autoconf

Tags: kali-linux, installation

I am using Kali Linux and try to install autoconf. When I run the code

> `apt-get install autoconf`

I get the following error:

> Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Here is the screen shot that I got error from installing:
[image]

Comment: The error message is actually telling you what to do. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/399627#399627) might be useful for you to read

Comment: try `apt-get update` that should refresh your sources and allow this to work.  as @Joe mentions the clue is in the last line of your screenshot :)  If that command doesn't work, it's likely that your machine has Internet access issues, so that'd be the next port of call in the troubleshooting process